# How to pass references from parent table to child table in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am new to database.
my question is that i have created a table `signUp` whose columns are

> id, first name, last name, email and country.

and i want to create a table named `accout_recharge` whose columns are `(email,balance)`
and whenever i insert a record into signup table the newly added email in the signup table also appear in account_recharge table using references or foreign key or whatever is required but without duplication.

Comment: please post your query, we can help better then now. also i will suggest u to learn some basic before getting start

Comment: Thanks for the current help. Could you please refer me some link for learning basics of databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
CREATE TABLE signup (
     id INT NOT NULL,
     firstName varchar(50),
     lastName varchar(50),
     countryName varchar(50),
     emailName varchar(50),
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     index email_ind(emailName)    -- updated here 
) ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE accout_recharge(  
    id INT,
    balance DECIMAL,
    email varchar(50),    
    FOREIGN KEY (email ) REFERENCES signup (emailName)
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

[MySql Foreign Key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) here you find more detail about foreign key reference

**Update:** I forget to tell you that foreign key reference always some kind of `indexed` column. so you need to turn you email column in an index. that why you are getting error: 150

Comment: Thanks Bro! but account recharge table couldn't be created it gives some error may be because of different column name in signup of emailName and in the reference table it is just email.

Comment: it is still giving error!
Signup table is created but account_recharge is unable to create.With following error.
#1072 - Key column 'email' doesn't exist in table

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS signup;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accout_recharge;
and try upper query

Comment: No Signup table is dropped . then created but accout_recharge is not creadted

Comment: There is some mistake in FOREIGN KEY or References because when i remove that statement query executes sucessfully

Comment: Gess! Now both tables created.
Thanks Nikson!